# Is it possible to enable CloudWatch on a running EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-iam

It looks like Amazon has a ready-built IAM role to grant instances CloudWatch write access. ( A more restrictive one [could also be created if necessary](https://serverfault.com/questions/532675/which-permissions-policies-for-iam-role-to-be-used-with-cloudwatch-monitoring-sc))

But it appears you [cannot attach an IAM role to a running instance.](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=97487)

Am I missing something? Do I really have to re-instantiate my whole fleet to enable CloudWatch? I'm reluctant to save plaintext credentials on each host for security reasons.

Comment: Update: specifically I was attempting to add a disk utilization monitor. This and related metrics (like cpu and memory utilization) require some sort of agent or process running on the host. The Amazon cloudwatch scripts called from cron with locally saved credentials for a cloudwatch IAM user did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're talking about custom CloudWatch metrics. You don't have to restart any instances to enable them. You can create a group in IAM with the following policy and add a user to this group:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "****************",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "cloudwatch:PutMetricData"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Then you basically copy this user's credentials to awscred file and add the perl script to cron. Yes, I had to copy credentials to each machine where custom metrics collection is enabled.

Comment: This works, thanks. I ended up implementing it with a restricted IAM account specifically for this purpose. I've also created an IAM role which I can attach to future instances. This should obviate the need to store credentials locally on the instance (limited though they may be).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered simply modifying the existing IAM role to enable writes to CloudWatch? That change should take effect immediately and does not require instance reboot or relaunch.

Comment: This would work too, but I didn't have any IAM roles attached. So it wasn't possible in my case. I ended up creating a new IAM user specifically for this task and using that.